# Is it possible for random quantum fluctiations in the Universe to cause a new Big Bang before the death of the Universe?

Tags: universe

I have read in some distant future predictions that after some years(numbers like 10<sup>1500</sup> years) random quantum fluctuations could produce a new Big Bang.

Is that possible, and is it possible now, or certain conditions must be met?

Many sources also state that after that much time there will be only subatomic particles left in the Universe, and if a new Big Bang doesn't happen it will end in heat death scenario(permanent end)?